# Not able to populate the data into the fields based on the dropdown selection

Tags: angularjs

I am kind of new to angular trying to develop an application with CRUD operations. i am trying to hold the value of a drop down for further usage and populate the data into the fields based on the selection.

Not able to populate the data into the fields based on the selection of the dropdown: if i use "product.id as product.name for product in listProducts" instead of ng-options="product.name for product in listProducts"

any help is appreciated thanks in advance

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myModule", []);
myapp.controller("myController", function($scope){
var listProducts = [
  { id: '100', name: "Macy", price: 200, quantity: 2 },
  { id: '101', name: "JCPenny", price: 400, quantity: 1 },
  { id: '102', name: "Primark", price: 300, quantity: 3 },
  { id: '103', name: "H&M", price: 600, quantity: 1 }
 ];
 
 $scope.listProducts = listProducts;
  
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myModule">
 <head>
  <title> CRUD Operations </title>
  <script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="myController">
  Here i am populating the data into the fields without holding the id as the value in the dropdown which is successfull
  <div>
  <select ng-model=search ng-options="product.name for product in listProducts">
  </select> 
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Edit Information </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>ID</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="search.id"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="search.name"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Price</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="search.price"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody> 
  </table>
    </div>
   if i hold the id as value display the name in the dropdown , not able to populate the data into the fields 
<div>
<select ng-model=searchProduct ng-options="product.id as product.name for product in listProducts"></select>  
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Edit Information </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>ID</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchProduct.id"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchProduct.name"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Price</td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchProduct.price"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody> 
  </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you use the first method you describe?

Comment: @AlexandreNucera, i have to retain and pass the value(id) for my CRUD operations. Please suggest any other approach. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are almost there,

In your controller, simply assign an empty variable in your scope to hold the value selected:

```
var myapp = angular.module("myModule", []);
myapp.controller("myController", function($scope){
var listProducts = [
        { id: '100', name: "Macy", price: 200, quantity: 2 },
        { id: '101', name: "JCPenny", price: 400, quantity: 1 },
        { id: '102', name: "Primark", price: 300, quantity: 3 },
        { id: '103', name: "H&M", price: 600, quantity: 1 }
    ];

    $scope.listProducts = listProducts;
    $scope.selectedProduct = {};
  });
```

and bind it to the select:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-options="product.name for product in listProducts">
```

Now, wherever you need the id, simply access it through `$scope.selectedProduct.id`